# How do I get awsiamrole credentials from gradle?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gradle, amazon-iam

I am developing a spring boot web application with Gradle.

The problem I have is that I can't run the Gradle project through aws role.

I don't think there's any proof of work on aws iam role in the Gradle.

When the role was not used for the first time, it worked normally.

There is no problem with the policy for role.
What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Below is the credentials of ./aws.

from

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id= my-key
aws_secret_access_key= my-key
```

to

```
[iam-user]
aws_access_key_id=my-key
aws_secret_access_key=my-key

[default]
source_profile = iam-user
role_arn = my-role-arn
```

Comment: Does your Spring BOOT app work when using [default] creds?

Comment: @smac2020 Hello.
Yes, using the default profile above, it works normally.